# C++ project is out of date error when build on visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to build c++ project in visual studio 2008 which was made in visual studio 2010.
It is giving **project is out of date** error    .
I think its a kind of linker error ,nothing from google worked.

it is an open gl c++ project .
Kindly help me 
[image: Errors list]

Comment: Those are compile errors, you need to fix them.

Comment: these errors don't come on other machines compiler

Comment: They are still compile errors.  What's the difference between the two machines?

Comment: Code that compiles in VS2010 doesn't necessarily compile in VS2008.

Comment: source machine has VS 2010 installed and target machine has VS 2008 installed @RetiredNinja

Comment: Not sure what you're showing with the image, none of those errors are the one you're asking about. When you have errors, start with #1, fix it, and continue on. Fixing the errors in some random order isn't the best approach. Any number of errors further down the list may be resolved by fixing one higher up.

Comment: Since 2008 won't read 2010 projects I assume you rebuilt it manually and something is different.  Best to post the actual code and errors as text here so we can see them.

Comment: code is fine ,there is no code errors .i am sure about it ,it just says project is out of date and show these errors which are not actually errors .I fixed the same problem along ago but right now i dont remember what i did ,The problem is related to entry point and linker @RetiredNinja

Comment: Saying the `std` namespace doesn't exist seems like a code/include issue to me, but if you say it's not I guess it's not.  Good luck fixing it.

Comment: Would love to see the code these errors go with then.

Answer (score 1):

You are right ,problem is there in linker or entry point like difference between int main and int _main()
just go in the properties of the poject and set entry point

Comment: ThankGod someone got my point